# ROM variable not getting the defined value

Tags: c, embedded

I'm working on developing a software stack for automotives based on a Renesas RL78 controller. Getting straight into the problem, variables declared const(ROM variables) are not getting initialized with the defined value.

Ex : const uint8 var_test = 1;

On the other hand, global,static variables are getting initialized.

Is this the problem with the startup code? kindly suggest...

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: How are you deciding that the variable isn't initialized correctly? Can you make a minimal reproducing test case?

Comment: @joe, i'm using IAR compiler

Comment: @KerrekSB i m checking that through a provided watch window, i didnot make any specific test case for it.

Comment: Consider using the IAR-specific keyword __flash.  On versions of IAR I've used, const is put into the RAM segment and initialized at startup, even though you'd think it would be ROM.  Do you have a low_level_init() function?  Does it return 1?

Comment: @ROSS : start up code has a low_level_init call, and need not be explicitly called, as i have seen it as returning 1 in one of its explicity written c file, installed in the program files of the IAR workbench. and i haven't noticed the qualifier __flash till now.. have to check with it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually const isn't enough of a qualifier to allow variables to go in ROM (you could always cast it away). Usually you need to mark the variable with something compiler specific to indicate what you want, or perhaps a compiler flag to indicate your intention. I believe the IAR compiler uses the @ symbol to allow you to specify a location for a variable. I'd check its manual :-)

Comment: But it is said, in the compiler documentation that variables declared const shall go into ROM.And yes as you said, we can cast away anytime later, but it is not being modified here.

Comment: So you're confident it's in the right location, in ROM where you expect it, but just the initialisation is failing?

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers, probably your const variable isn't placed into a ROM section.

You need to tell the compiler/linker where to place it.

With an IAR toolchain it's probably something like

```
#pragma SET_CONST_PAGE(ConstArea)

const int myVariable1=42;
const int myVariable2=4711;

#pragma SET_DEFAULT_CONST_PAGE
```

But that your debugger doesn't show the correct value is another problem, it's possible that the variable is optimized.
To be sure what happens look into the map file and look (with the debugger) at assembly level what is done.

Comment: But it should show where your variables are placed (which sections/addresses)

Comment: yeah, i do'nt have any idea why it isn't showing the data going into ROM segment.. may be optimization issues..but have to look through it... ROM segment data is placed as NEAR_CONST and this area is been given around 280 bytes... but an explicit ROM variable is not shown like where it is allocated.. but at the latest i have checked that the ROM variable value is getting defined to the value given but couldn't access the address of it..

Answer (score 0):

Non-static `const` variables are not "constant enough" to go into ROM, typically. If you inspect a function using such variables, you'll probably see that the function's preamble has code to initialize the variables on the local stack.

Of course, startup code can't fix this, since it (by definition) can't write the values into ROM.

Comment: so you say that the memory space is running out of ROM ?

Comment: No, he said that your const variables are not linked into ROM sections, probably they still resides in RAM

Answer (score 0):

Const objects are not required by the language to be located in ROM, but merely to be read-only after initialisation, and for reasons of performance on some targets for example a compiler might deliberatly avoid doing so.

The [IAR RL78 C/C++ Compiler Reference Guide](ftp://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/rl78/CRL78-1.pdf) states :

> "Static and global objects declared const and located in far memory are allocated in 
>   ROM. const declared saddr objects are allocated in RAM and initialized by the runtime 
>   system at startup. const declared near objects are allocated according to the option 
>   --near_const_location.
>
> In C++, objects that require runtime initialization cannot be placed in ROM."

Refer to the `#pragma location` directive or the `@` operator in the manual, these allow placement at absolute addresses or within named memory segments.